# Selenium, Download Dynamic Captcha, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Because of the need to check like 100+ registration numbers, I decided to create a script which will do this for me, as I need to test these often.

The idea is that I have to visit the following website:
https://www.anaf.ro/inactivi/index.jsp

Where I input a registration number in the first field, and I have to input the captcha in the second. The captcha is quite easy to solve, and it is straight forward, as there are already available libraries for python, but the problem that I am facing is that the "src" attribute of the image, goes to a dynamic url.

Is there any way of saving the image which is displayed when using the .get on the webdriver?

This is how I am trying to solve the problem:

```
from captcha_solver import CaptchaSolver
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.anaf.ro/inactivi/index.jsp")

time.sleep(5)

elem = driver.find_element_by_name('inputCui')  # Find the first input box
elem.send_keys('17741254')   # Input the desired code
```

Or maybe, if someone has another idea on how I can approach the problem, I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I managed to solve it, I will simply take a screenshot of the page, then crop it, after that I will decode the captcha. Here is the code for those interested:

```
def get_captcha(driver, element, path):
    location = element.location
    size = element.size
    driver.save_screenshot(path)
    image = Image.open(path)
    left = location['x']
    top = location['y']
    right = location['x'] + size['width']
    bottom = location['y'] + size['height']
    image = image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))
    image.save(path, 'png')

img = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[1]")
get_captcha(driver, img, "captcha.png")
```